# "provideCredentialWithoutUserInteractionForIdentity:" is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, autofill

I have an app that autofills the password on iOS 12. Now I want to implement this function:

```
- (void)provideCredentialWithoutUserInteractionForIdentity:(ASPasswordCredentialIdentity *)credentialIdentity;
```

But I cant get it to work like it should.

AutoFill is enabled in settings and also enabled for my app.

I've read the documentation but this doens't help me. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/ascredentialproviderviewcontroller/2977554-providecredentialwithoutuserinte?language=objc

I've tried calling this function from `viewDidLoad`, `prepareCredentialListForServiceIdentifiers`,.. but this is stupid and definitely won't work.

```
- (void)provideCredentialWithoutUserInteractionForIdentity:(ASPasswordCredentialIdentity *)credentialIdentity {
    ASPasswordCredential *credential = [[ASPasswordCredential alloc] initWithUser:@"theUsername" password:@"thePassword"];
    [self.extensionContext completeRequestWithSelectedCredential:credential completionHandler:nil];
}
```

The function should show the credentials above the keyboard, but this doesn't happen. It just shows the default "Passwords" button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have some `ASPasswordCredentialIdentity`s for your domain/url in `ASCredentialIdentityStore`. (These are records with some unique recordIdentifier, that doesn't hold password but hold data that can help you decide what password you should take from some secure storage of your choice.)
2. When you open a website, iOS looks up the `ASCredentialIdentityStore`, and shows a big button for quick login if there's a matching record. If you hit the button - this is only when `provideCredentialWithoutUserInteraction` callback is executed. Your task is to work with `ASPasswordCredentialIdentity` passed as an argument (it has `recordIdentifier` field) and find matching password for it (in your database/keychain/etc.) When you have password - you create `ASPasswordCredential` and pass it to `self.extensionContext.completeRequest`. Also make sure to call extensionContext.cancelRequest in case of any errors.

here's my example

```swift
override func provideCredentialWithoutUserInteraction(for credentialIdentity: ASPasswordCredentialIdentity) {
           
        let databaseIsUnlocked = false
        if (databaseIsUnlocked) {
            
            // this function queries my custom keychain records by recordIdentifier (Generic Passwords) to find matching password
            getItemForRecordId(identifier: credentialIdentity.recordIdentifier) { password, err in
                
                guard password != nil else {
                    print("password was nil")
                    self.extensionContext.cancelRequest(withError: NSError(domain: ASExtensionErrorDomain, code:ASExtensionError.userInteractionRequired.rawValue))
                    return;
                }
                let passwordCredential = ASPasswordCredential(user: credentialIdentity.user, password: password as! String);
                self.extensionContext.completeRequest(withSelectedCredential: passwordCredential, completionHandler: nil);
                
            };
            
        } else {
            self.extensionContext.cancelRequest(withError: NSError(domain: ASExtensionErrorDomain, code:ASExtensionError.userInteractionRequired.rawValue))
        }
    }
```